# "coredumpctl" cannot read core dump, gives message file is not readable or no such file or directory?

Tags: linux-kernel, core-dump

I am issuing the following commands:

```
coredumpctl list
Mon 2019-11-18 23:58:19 GMT   19043  1000  1000  31 missing   /opt/google/chrome/chrome
Mon 2019-11-18 23:58:19 GMT   19062  1000  1000  31 missing   /opt/google/chrome/chrome
Tue 2019-11-19 15:52:55 GMT   22332  1000  1000   6 missing   /usr/bin/texstudio
```

Followed by:

```
coredumpctl gdb 22332
Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.texstudio.1000.bb1cfb6b67f2423fac681d721ee1ba02.22332.1574178774000000.lz4 (inaccessible)
File "/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.texstudio.1000.bb1cfb6b67f2423fac681d721ee1ba02.22332.1574178774000000.lz4" is not readable: No such file or directory
```

Which dumps the stack trace and gives the above two messages about storage being inaccessible and file not readable or found.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `df -h /var/lib/systemd/coredump/` gives the following
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`
`/dev/nvme0n1p2  195G  169G   16G  92% /`

Answer (score 0):

There are two common things you could be getting wrong.

Often a core dump is "inaccessible" because the program was run as a different user ID from you.  This means you do not have permission.  The quick solution is to run `coredumpctl` as root, e.g. using `sudo coredumpctl`.

I guess that is not your problem.  These coredumps are from user ID 1000.  I guess your user has ID 1000, because it is the first (and probably only) non-root login created on your system.

Secondly, [systemd-coredump](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html) has some settings in [coredump.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/coredump.conf.html), about how much disk space it is allowed to use.  It looks like if you have less than 15% disk space free, core dumps will not be created at all.  (Unless you change this setting).

You can check your available disk space using the command `df -h` or `df -h /var/lib/systemd/coredump/`.

(And to see the total absolute size used by core dumps, you can run `du -sh /var/lib/systemd/coredump/`.)

> MaxUse=, KeepFree=
>
> Enforce limits on the disk space taken up by externally stored core dumps. MaxUse= makes sure that old core dumps are removed as soon as the total disk space taken up by core dumps grows beyond this limit (defaults to 10% of the total disk size). KeepFree= controls how much disk space to keep free at least (defaults to 15% of the total disk size). Note that the disk space used by core dumps might temporarily exceed these limits while core dumps are processed. Note that old core dumps are also removed based on time via systemd-tmpfiles(8). Set either value to 0 to turn off size-based clean-up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Everything is commented out be default in coredump.conf. 
You might be right that maybe coredumps are not generated cause ATM I have 8% of free disk space.

Comment: @KirkWalla (the original commented out lines tell you what the default settings are. of course, if you modified something and later commented it out again, it could get confusing :-).

Comment: BTW my coredump is only 8.0M on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `coredumpctl list` says `missing` on each of the dumps, and the final error message was `No such file or directory`.

I'm guessing your distribution has a regular cron job/systemd timer that cleans up old core dumps (weekly, maybe?). It has cleaned up the actual core dump files, and only a small log entry that tells `coredumpctl` that such a dump used to exist was left over.